How to modify CarrierConfigManager values on Android 8.1 using ADB (no root)?
I'm trying to enable VoLTE on an Android 8.1 device by setting KEY_CARRIER_VOLTE_PROVISIONED_BOOL in CarrierConfigManager to 1.
On Android 12+, there is an app called Pixel IMS that uses Shizuku to modify CarrierConfigManager values. However, Pixel IMS doesn’t work on Android 8.1. I’m looking for a way to achieve this using ADB, without rooting the device.
So far, I haven’t found any ADB commands that directly modify CarrierConfigManager values. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe some workaround with ADB, debug permissions, or other tools?
What I Tried:

Tried using ADB commands:

I looked for ways to directly access or modify CarrierConfigManager values through ADB commands but couldn't find any specific commands that work on Android 8.1.

Explored tools like Pixel IMS:

I know Pixel IMS, combined with Shizuku, works on Android 12+ for changing these values, but it’s incompatible with Android 8.1.
What I Expected:
I expected to find a way to modify KEY_CARRIER_VOLTE_PROVISIONED_BOOL using ADB or another method without requiring root access.
What Happened:
I couldn’t find any direct solution for Android 8.1. No ADB command seems to allow direct modification of CarrierConfigManager values, and tools like Pixel IMS don’t support older Android versions.
